# Programming challenge “Greatest Odd Divisor”

Tags: java, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I am trying to solve a programming problem on a coding platform. When I submit the code on the coding platform, it throws a "Time Limit Exceeded" error. Can someone check my solution and help optimize it?

> **A food delivery company X** gets a lot of orders every day. It charges some
> commission from the restaurants on these orders. More formally, if an order
> value is K, X charges a commission which is the greatest odd divisor of K. You
> can assume that an order value will always be an integer. **Given an order value
> N, and let C(N) be the greatest odd-divisor of N, output the value of C(1) +
> C(2) + C(3) + … + C(N).**
>
> **INPUT :** Input will be an integer, N, the order value. 1 <= N <= 10^9
>
> **OUTPUT :** Single integer which is the answer

```java
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {
    static double GOD(double num)
    {
        if(num%2!=0)
        {
            return num;
        }
        else
        {
            for (double i = num / 2; i > 0 ;i--)
            {
                if (num % i == 0 && i % 2 != 0)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
     }
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
   
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double num = sc.nextDouble();
    double sum = 0;
    for(double i = 1; i<=num; i++)
        {
        sum = sum + GOD(i);
    }
    System.out.println((int)sum);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be using `double`s to perform integer arithmetic. Stick to `int` or `long`.

This is a brute-force search that follows the instructions very literally.  That is the wrong approach. Similar to [Project Euler Problem 3](/a/48185/9357), the fast way to find the largest factor is by finding the smallest factors. Just divide by 2 as many times as possible.

Example:

$$360 = 2^3 \cdot 45$$

The largest odd divisor is therefore 45.

Answer (score 3):

First some remarks to your code (in addition to what @200_success
already said):

- Use more horizontal space and make the spacing *consistent*. 
  `if (num % i == 0 && i % 2 != 0)` is better readable than `if(num%2!=0)`.
- Fix the indentation.
- You don't need an `else` block after `if (condition) { ... ; return; }`.
- You have put the computation of the "greatest odd divisor" into
  a separate function `GOD()` which is good. The next step would be to 
  compute the sum of odd divisors in a separate function. That keeps
  the main function short and allows you to add test cases easily.

About the performance: @200_success already made an excellent suggestion
how to improve the determination of the greatest odd divisor.
The suggested algorithm is probably the fastest for a *single integer.*

However, the programming challenge requires to compute 
`C(1) + C(2) + C(3) + … + C(N)` for *large* numbers `N` up to `10^9`.
Computing `C(i)` separately for each number and adding the values
*may* not be fast enough for that challenge.

In that case you'll have to find a different algorithm, and I'll try
to describe a possible approach.

First compute the result `C(1) + C(2) + C(3) + … + C(N)` for small
values `N = 1, 2, 3, …`, that will give

```
1, 2, 5, 6, 11, 14, 21, 22, 31, 36, 47, 50, 63, 70, 85, …
```

If you are lucky then you'll "see" a pattern, and find some formula how
to compute the numbers for arbitrary `N` quickly. If you don't find
a pattern, then look up the sequence at the
[The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences®](http://oeis.org).
And indeed, it is listed as [A135013](http://oeis.org/A135013).
Even better, there is a PROG section with code snippets for different
programming languages, e.g. for [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), a computer algebra system:

```
(PARI) a(n)=sum(k=1, log(n)\log(2)+1, round(n/2^k)^2)
```

As you can see, there is a summation, but it is limited by
`log(N)`, not by `N`, which is a huge difference for large numbers!

Now translate that to Java –
I don't want to spoil the fun of finding the final solution yourself!
 It should not be too difficult if you
know that in PARI/GP, `/` is the "normal division", e.g. `6/4 = 3/2`,
and `\` is the integer division with truncation, e.g. `6\4 = 1`.

On my MacBook the resulting Java program computed the output
for `N = 10^9` in 0.157 sec.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>         sum = sum + GOD(i);
> ```

In Java and most C-based languages, you can write this as

```
        sum += GOD(i);
```

Which is just a shorter way of writing the same thing.  This works for most arithmetic [operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

> ```
> import java.util.*;
> ```

You could just as well say

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

As that is the only one that you actually use.

While some people like to save space by using the `*`, many (including me) prefer if all the imports are spelled out.